# Any (preferably free & open source) software for posting simple & basic pages? (Not a wiki) (ie: similar to the software craigslist uses)

Tags: open-source, cms

I apparently do not know how to Google for such. But I really an curious to know if it exists to add for my site so that users can submit such pages on their own, also have the choose categories for such pages. (Keep the layout simple, the most ideal of what I am looking for would, in fact, have Times New Roman as the font w/ a White page background). The site I want to host is not entirely like Craigslist, But the idea of

- Posting simple pages (but not quite like a blog)
- Posting images on those pages (I may have to use another image hosting server)
- Have pages filed into categories (best example: location)

Not mandatory, however, is the 'contacting posters' feature.

I do not want it to be a wiki because I simply don't want anyone editing pages from someone else.

Comment: Many wikis allow to set edit permissions, so you could have a wiki where only page owners/creators are allowed to edit their pages.

Comment: The only wiki I am willing to use for this would be UseMod (for appearance reasons). I have heard there is a way to make read-only pages on there, but that is only controllable by the admin.

Comment: It looks like UseMod can handle that. From http://www.usemod.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?AdminFeatures ...  Lock editing for all pages (only admins and "editors" can edit):    http://www.usemod.com/cgi-bin/um9.pl?action=editlock&set=1    Although I am not sure if that means that you can set & forget that as default.  If in doubt, why not ask usemod AT usemod DOT c o m

Comment: BUT, from  http://www.usemod.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?UseModWiki/UseModFAQ#Q_Is_usemodwiki_orphanware       Q: Is usemodwiki orphanware?

    A1: Probably yes. It has not changed much since 2003.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, Mawg. I am 95% sure it's orphanware too. The support email doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[WordPress](http://wordpress.org) is the clear choice.

The default ["User Role"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) on WordPress is "Subscriber", but if you change the default user role to "Author", then your registered users can post and edit their own posts but not do anything else. The "Contributor" role allows them to write posts but because they cannot publish them it essentially gives you the ability to moderate posts.

Comment: Can I customize Wordpress to a layout simelar to ones like Craigslist? Or even my own via a CSS file for the pages?

Comment: Yes, quite easily. There are thousands of free themes, thousands more paid themes, and you can make your own them. I even made my own theme, but I didn't finish it, so I am not super happy with it. I strongly suggest you use a pre-made theme however because the learning curve is steep. Actually, I just did a search for "wordpress craigslist theme" and there are multiple options but I have no idea of their quality. The point: you can almost certainly get what you want with relatively minimal effort.

Comment: Thank you again. Can it also file the pages into curtain folders/categories?

Comment: If it can be done with HTML/CSS/JS, then WP can do it. If you want to experiment for free, open a WordPress.COM account. WordPress.ORG is the more general resource, especially for people who run WP on their own server or host. There is also a WP StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) or [Drupal](http://drupal.org). While Wordpress is easier to start with (a bit more non-developer friendly), Drupal is more advanced and sophisticated system that will grow with your needs. From the list of current requirements, Wordpress would certainly be good enough to address your needs.